# How to set minimum length of characters in inputText for bootsfaces?

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I'm trying to use boots-faces for the first time and was looking for some validations at the client side like minimum length, maximum length or exact length.

I was able to find **maxLength** but I'm struggling to find how to do other length validations. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Only client side? It is not trustworthy. Use instead `<f:validateLength  minimum="..." maximum="..." />` or https://stackoverflow.com/a/18487861/1391249

Answer (score 4):

We didn't implement it yet. Please open a feature request at https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues.

By the way, how do you want the validation messages to be displayed? Currently, `maxLength` is simply added to the HTML sourcecode. So it's up to the browser to interpret it. In the case of `maxLength`, that's easy because it suffices to stop accepting input after reaching the maximum length.

`minLength`, `exactLength`, and `pattern` are different. They have to be able to show regular error messages. That amounts to finding the corresponding `h:message(s)`, `b:message(s)`, or `p:message(s)` tag and populating it with error messages on the client side.

The PrimeFaces team implemented the feature. That was a lot of work, and my perception is that few people miss it. I'd be happy to be proven wrong because the BootsFaces story is all about shifting logic to the client.

In the meantime, just follow the suggestion of @Tiny above and [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485090/optional-field-with-minimum-length-validation-in-jsf/18487861#18487861) and use the AJAX engine:

```
 <b:input value="...">
     <f:validateLength minimum="..." maximum="..." />
     <f:validateRegex pattern="^$|^[A-Za-z-_./\s]{2,50}$" />
 </b:input>
```